# JQuery Datatable Rows linked to Razor Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datatables, razor-pages

I am using the current version of JQuery datatables 1.10.25, with Razor pages, and SQL server. I am unable to figure out how to make Datatable rows selectable for CRUD. I need each row to route to the same Razor page for Update but also carry the data from the row. How do I syntax after the

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#myTable").DataTable({ *my information*})
```

to route to the Razor update page, and pass the row data to the page?

The table is populated with my SQL server information, but I don't seem to be able to add the routing/passing i need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to pass row data to handler:

Model:

```
public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

cshtml:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<select id="ddlGroup">
    <option>Choose Id</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

</select>
<table id="taskDt">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
var table;
    function LoadData() {
        table = $("#taskDt").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: '?handler=GET',
                type: 'GET',
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "width": "50%" },
                { "data": "name", "width": "50%" },
                {
                    render: function (data) {
                        return `


                                           <button type="button" onclick=getData(this) class="btn btn-primary">
                                                     Edit Staff
                                           </button>
                                  `;
                    }
                },
                ],
            paging: true,
            responsive: true,
            searching: true,

            ordering: true,
            order: [[1, "asc"]]
        });
    }
    function getData(t) {
        var data = table.row($(t).parents('tr')).data();
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?handler=ChangeData',
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        })
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        LoadData();
    })
```

Then you can get the row data in handler with `public void OnPostChangeData(Test t)`